# Facebook API video embed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have been looking around and cant find a way to embed a Facebook video on my site using the Facebook API... i know they introduced the embed video functionality, but was wondering if they had a way like with the YouTube API to embed videos so i was able to manipulate the video more like you can with YouTube.

certain things i was wanting to do was trigger an action when the video has ended, ad my own poster image, these things are all achievable via the YouTube API

thanks in advance

Comment: Those feature does not exist

Comment: thank you, saves me looking arround